# How to replace {“bcz”,u,thr} with {“because”,you,there} in whole text? (Text-ming)

Tags: text-mining

Can someone please explain with example R/Python code to replace {“bcz”,u,thr} with {“because”,you,there} in whole text? (Text-ming)

Answer (score 0):

The remove_words function gets a string and returns another string with making your required changes. Make sure that regex package is installed properly to be able to run this code and get the desired output. Through regex you can define the compilers for extracting each pattern of strings you want to change:

```
import regex as re    
def remove_words(my_line):
   new_line =''
   compiler_thr = re.compile(r"thr")
   compiler_u = re.compile(r"u")
   compiler_bcz = re.compile(r"bcz")
   for i in my_line.split():
      if i in compiler_thr.findall(my_line):
         new_line = new_line + ' ' + 'there'
      elif i in compiler_u.findall(my_line):
         new_line = new_line + ' ' + 'you'
      elif i in compiler_bcz.findall(my_line):
         new_line = new_line + ' ' + 'because'
      else:
         new_line = new_line + ' ' + i
   return new_line
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code above is a python code.